# RDLC Reports and SQL Server CLR

Tags: sql, clr, rdlc

I have a local RDLC report, simple, works on my machine (of course). Deployed to a user's machine with Windows XP and it throws the error "Can't load module Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll because the file or one of it's dependencies is missing".  I tried the easy fix first, copied the DLL into her bin folder where the program resides.  No luck, same error.  Next installed the SQL Server CLR reporting library in hopes that it would solve the problem.  No luck, same error.  What part of the CLR do I need to install (there are about 20 pieces it seems)?  Not the CLR, then what do I need to install to get the reports to run.

This is a .Net 4 app, all of the system binaries are installed in the program folder, just to make sure it will work with all client's machines (without having to download and install .Net 4 on them).

Thanks

Jeff